# cdbflite Use /filter to find empty lines

Tags: file, filter, dbf

I have a file user.dbf, I want to filter all mail that are empty, I searched on the internet to find a way to filter the empty field but without success.

```
user.dbf : id ; username ; password ; mail
```

Using the cdbflite software, I tried to use this command :

```
cdbflite.exe user.dbf /filter:mail=' ' /select:id,username > log.csv
```

but it return : Invalid Filter

Help me please :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excerpted from http://www.whitetown.com/cdbflite/cl/

```
    /filter:condition
    /f:condition

    Installation of the filter. The filter allows to select of some
    records which satisfying to some condition. Allowable to use several
    conditions in one filter and/or some filters. In the latter case they
    was united as condition 'AND'. For example:

    /filter:name=Smith - to select people with name "Smith"

    /filter:name=Smith&age>30   - to select people with name "Smith" and
                                  age more them 30 year

    /filter:name=Smith&age{30   - to select people with name "Smith" and
                                  age less them 30 year

    /filter:name=Smith;name=Gates - to select people with name "Smith" or
                                    "Gates"

    /filter:name=Smith|name=Gates - to select people with name "Smith" or
                                    "Gates"

    /filter:name~uck - to select people, containing a substring "uck".

    /filter:name=A /filter:age=30 - it's same as
    /filter:name=A&age=30

   If the compared expression contains blanks, you should to conclude
   expression in quotes.

    /filter:name="John Smith"
```

As a guess, try using double quotes and try having no space between them:

```
/filter:mail=""
```

If that doesn't work, I don't think it's possible.